# Finding the value of a crossroad stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am studying stohastic processes, currently crossroad processes so I have to prove that:
$$VARX_{n}=E(VAR(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))+VAR(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))$$
Where $X_{n}$ is the current position and $X_{n-1}$ is the previous.

We are given that:

$$EX_{n}=E(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))$$
and Wald's equation:
$$EZ=EXEM,Z=\sum_{i=1}^{M}x_{i}$$
My attempt:
$$VarX_{n}=E(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))^{2}-E(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1})^{2})$$
$$VarX_{n}=E(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))^{2}-E(\sum x_{i} P(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))^{2}$$
$$VarX_{n}=E(E(X_{n}|X_{n-1}))^{2}-E(\frac{\sum x_{i}P(X_{n}X_{n-1})}{P(X_{n-1})})^{2}$$

And here I realise that this is not the way ..

Can you please show me the proof of this statement or suggest me a resource where I can find the answer?

Comment: $VARX=E(VAR(X|Y))+VAR(E(X|Y))$ is a classical result. See e.g.,formula *** in (https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/384G04/condmeanvar3.pdf)

Comment: Thank you ! If you want enter an answer so we can complete this question

Comment: All right like this. Thank you too.

Comment: What is a `crossroad stochastic process`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from a more general result, which is:

$$Var(X)=E(Var(X|Y))+Var(E(X|Y))$$

See e.g., formula *** in (https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/384G04/condmeanvar3.pdf)